# Add digits to a long number (13+ digits long)

Tags: .net, numbers

The user enters the full first card number and the last full number, so I need to get a range of card numbers from the first to the last. then handle each card number.

What I did is I split the first number and then I increase the last few numbers using a for loop.

The problem is that if the first digit of the last 5 are a 0 then its ignored by the loop, so I have all cards missing a digit from the middle of all card numbers...

```
Dim StartFirstNumbers = StartCard.Substring(0, StartCard.Length - 5)
Dim StartLast9 = StartCard.Substring(StartFirstNumbers.Length, StartCard.Length - StartFirstNumbers.Length)

Dim EndFirstNumbers = EndCard.Substring(0, EndCard.Length - 5)
Dim EndLast9 = EndCard.Substring(EndFirstNumbers.Length, EndCard.Length - EndFirstNumbers.Length)

For i As Integer = StartLast9 To EndLast9
    Row.CardNo = StartFirstNumbers & i
Next
```

I could check for that digit and handle it accordingly, but I feel there is a better way of doing that.

For example: if the card number is 98300100001 the last numbers would be "0001", the 'i' starts with 1 not 0001.

Comment: Can you post some example data of what happens?

Comment: I added a sample card number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
For i As Integer = StartLast9 To EndLast9
    Row.CardNo = StartFirstNumbers & i.ToString("D5")
Next
```

Comment: What behavior is it giving you and what do you expect it to give?  If that doesnt work I am not sure I understand the question...

Comment: Or try String.Format("{0:D5}", i)